# Microsoft Azure Graph API Subscription Errors on Validation request using Custom Api as Listener for notifications

Tags: c#, azure, microsoft-graph-api

I have looked at the post of people saying the resolved this issue by allowing the API to accept "text/plain".

Even though I have done so, I am still getting the below error:

> "{  \"error\": {    \"code\": \"InvalidRequest\",    \"message\": \"Subscription validation request failed. Notification endpoint must
>   respond with 200 OK to validation request.\",    \"innerError\": {
>   \"request-id\": \"ec325726-5b30-4cb1-bec5-3ba3debf88b0\",
>   \"date\": \"2020-03-23T13:02:01\"    }  }}"

I have tested my API on Postman using the same request Microsoft sends when they are validating an API. 
All seems to be fine in Postman.

The image shows Postman results:

[image: The image shows Postman results]

Please help.

Comment: Include your code snippet so that it can be reproducible.

Comment: POST https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/subscriptions
Content-Type: application/json
{
  "changeType": "updated",
  "notificationUrl": "https://<my api domanin>/api/Graph/ReceiveGraphNotification",
  "resource": "/users/mailboxSettings",
  "expirationDateTime": "2020-03-27T11:00:00.0000000Z",
  "clientState": "SecretClientState"
}

Comment: The listener:

   [HttpPost("ReceiveGraphNotification")]
        [Produces("text/plain")]
        public async Task<ActionResult<string>> ReceiveGraphNotification(string validationToken)
        {
            using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(Request.Body, Encoding.UTF8))
            {
                string response = await reader.ReadToEndAsync();

                return Content(validationToken, "text/plain");
            }
        }

Comment: Can you test your service again with the validation request under the misc folder of this collection? It is fine tuned to reflect the query sent by the graph and contains unit tests to validate each aspect and help narrow down the issue. https://github.com/microsoftgraph/microsoftgraph-postman-collections

Comment: I did run it under the misc folder on postman and all the tests passes with no errors.

PASS
Status test
PASS
Content type test
PASS
Response body test

Comment: It seems to get users/mailboxsetting changes does not work with webhooks according to this post : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/webhooks?view=graph-rest-1.0. are we understanding it correctly? We basically want to be notified when a user switches on / off their out of office in outlook so that our api gets notified via graphapi webhook

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Subscribing to user's mailbox settings for change notifications is not supported at the moment by Microsoft Graph. If you'd like to request support for such feature, please go to [uservoice](https://microsoftgraph.uservoice.com) and create/upvote an idea.
If it were to be added to supported resources for change notifications, it more than likely that the resource would be `/users/{userid}/mailboxsettings` as `/users/mailboxsettings` is not a valid resource on Microsoft Graph. (resources for subscriptions follow the same pattern as the URLs of the APIs)